# Can't call gnome-screenshot in C

Tags: 14.04, c, screenshot, gnome-screenshot

I want to call the command `gnome-screenshot -ac` in my C program using `system("gnome-screenshot -ac")` or `exec()` but they didn't work. I'm sure that this command works well because I can use it in the terminal. The same error occurs when I tried to call a bash script I write the command in. When I use `system()`, it says:

```
(gnome-screenshot:16564): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_from_surface: assertion 'width > 0 && height > 0' failed

(gnome-screenshot:16564): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_window_resize: assertion 'width > 0' failed

** (gnome-screenshot:16564): CRITICAL **: Unable to capture a screenshot of any window
```

When calling `execl("./screenshot.sh","screenshot",NULL)` in C:

```
(gnome-screenshot:16861): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_from_surface: assertion 'width > 0 && height > 0' failed

(gnome-screenshot:16861): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_window_resize: assertion 'width > 0' failed

** (gnome-screenshot:16861): CRITICAL **: Unable to capture a screenshot of any window
```

Why it is wrong and how to fix it?

I can see the cursor after I run it in my terminal but in my C program. I just want to capture the screen and the clipboard will be accessed by users. I'm doing this with 14.04.2. I just call the functions to call the command in C but it always causes some errors above.

Comment: the -a parameter is an interactive parameter, where the user needs to use the cursor to select an area of the visible screen.   Are you seeing such a cursor modification and are you able to select an area of the screen?

Comment: suggest posting a minimal complete (cleanly compiles) example that shows the problem,  so we can debug the problem further.

Comment: the -c parameter says the screen shot is to be placed in the clipboard.  How are you accessing that clipboard in your program?

Comment: I can see the cursor after I run it in my terminal but in my C program. I just want to capture the screen and the clipboard will be accessed by users. I'm doing this with ubuntu 14.04.2. I just call the functions to call the command in C but it always causes some errors above.

Comment: without posted code that demonstrates the problem, we are just guessing.  suggest, again, post a cleanly compiles small function that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Here is a simple program can cause the first problem: `void main(void){system("gnome-screenshot -ac")}`

Comment: Try  `void main(void){system("env")}` and compare with calling the `env` command in the terminal within which `gnome-screenshot` works fine. Are there any suspicious differences that could relate to gnome or the display?